# How to handle load errors in Xamarin.forms webview

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, webview

I'm developing an app for my client and have configured a WebView in my **Xamarin.forms** application. How do I handle errors (*like Address Unreachable, no internet, etc..*)

I have added **try clause and catch exception**. But it doesn't work and the default unreachable page comes on android and a blank page on iOS if there is no Internet

```
 try{WebView.Source = "http://viva-t.000webhostapp.com/vivaapp";}
catch (Exception){var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
                htmlSource.Html = @"<html><body><h1>An Error!!!!</h1><p>Could not be loaded</p></body></html>";
                WebView.Source = htmlSource;}
```

I expect "This page could not be loaded" but instead I see the original android error page: "net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE"

Comment: You can intercept the url with the 'OnNavigating' event and then handle it accordingly.

Comment: Could you answer it how with code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try handling the error as below in the webview navigated event.

```
  var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
  htmlSource.Html = @"<html><body><h1>An Error!!!!</h1><p>Could not be loaded</p></body></html>";
  var wb = new WebView();
  wb.Source = htmlSource;
  wb.Navigated += (s, e) =>
  {
    if(e.Result!= WebNavigationResult.Success)
    {
         //Handle error here!
    }
  };
```

Comment: No problem. Do mark the result as helpful/correct if it helped you!

Comment: Have marked it helpful as well as upvoted .. just not visible due to reputation low